# Gnuplot: how to draw polygon/contour from its vertices

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot, polygon

My data.txt file contains the 2D coordinates of points forming a segment of a polygon. These coordinates are evolving over time. The file is structured like this:

```
itr    nbr_pts   p1.x p1.y ...... pk.x pk.y
(itr+1) ..........
.....
```

where pk is the k-th point/vertex of the polygon and nb_pts is the number vertices.

My question is how to draw the 2D polygon from its vertices (p1, p2, ...pk) at a certain iteration (row)?

In addition, note that there is not only one data file/polygon but N ones: data1.txt .... dataN.txt

I tried something like this but did not work (Nbr of files =6)

```
N = 6 
set multiplot
plot for [i=0:N-1]  polygon_i = sprintf("%s/data%d.dat",filename, i)  polygon_i val=$2 for [j=1:$2] u (j+1):(j+1+1)  w lines
```

I know how many polygones/files there is (6 in this cae), but I have no prior knowledge on the number of columns in each file; the number of vertices can vary from a polygone to another.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea I have would need a modification in the structure of your files. For each iteration time, there is a block containing the `x` and `y` coordinates of the polygon's vertices:

```
# file: data1.txt

# itr 0
0 0
1 1
1 2
0 0


# itr 1
1 3
2 1
0 1
1 2
1 3


# itr 2
3 1
2 1
0 0
3 1
```

Notice that each block is separated by two empty lines. For iteration 0 (block 0 or `itr 0`) there is a polygon with three vertices, `itr 1` has four vertices, and `itr 2` has three vertices. To obtain a closed curve, it is needed to specify the end point, for example, for `itr 1` I put the point `1 3` twice.

For this file, we can plot the polygon at iteration `iter` as

```
iter = 1   # select block 1, or itr 1
plot "data1.txt" index iter w lp ps 2 pt 7
```

If you have several files, then try

```
# option 1
nbr  = 6      # number of files
iter = 1      # select block 1, or itr 1

plot for [i=1:nbr] "data".i.".txt" index iter w lp ps 2 pt 7 title "".i

#option 2
files = system("ls data*.txt")   # get all datafiles in folder
iter = 1                         # select block 1, or itr 1

plot for [data in files] data index iter w lp ps 2 pt 7 title data
```