# How to do GNUPlot scatter plot with closed lines?

Tags: gnuplot

I plot a CSV file in scatter-plot with connecting lines with gnuplot using the following command:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 1 pt 7 pi -1 ps 1
set pointintervalbox 1.25

plot "values.csv" using 1:2 with lp ls 1
```

It looks great, but what I get is an opened polygon because gnuplot doesn't draw the line connecting the first point and the last.

How do I get gnuplot to connect the first and last points so I get a closed polygon?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32793123/2174266), [and this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29018902/2174266) on SO.

Comment: @vagoberto the linked answers are no solutions to this question, since there the first datapoint is _already_ added, at the end which is apparently not the case here, otherwise OP's polygon would not be open.

Comment: @theozh I think that's the reason I didn't post it as an answer 8 years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is as suggested in the comments by modifying your data file. However, if you want to get fancy you can do some `awk` on-the-fly preprocessing to append the first data point to the end of the file.

Consider the following data file:

```
# Some comment for the sake of generality
0 0
1 1
2 1
2 0
```

Which looks like this without any processing (e.g., `plot "data" w l`):

[image]

We remove comments and add the first line to the end of the file:

```
datafile = "< grep -v '#' data | awk '{if(NR==1) {i += 1; temp = $0; print \
$0;} else {i += 1; print $0;}} END {print temp}'"

plot datafile w l
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't show data, but I can assume that you just have n-datapoints for a n-polygon.
There is no reason why gnuplot should automatically close the curve to a polygon when plotting `with lines` or `with linespoints`. This would mean: adding the first datapoint again at the end.
You have to do this yourself.
You can do this via external tools like in Miguel's solution.

You can also do it with *gnuplot only* which would be *platform-independent*. Basically, you store the first and the last data point in `x0,y0` and `x1,y1`, respectively and plot a closing line `with vectors`.

**Data:** `SO32954260.dat`

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
2 0
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot closed polygon
reset

FILE = "SO32954260.dat"

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key noautotitle
set style line 1 lc rgb '#ff0000' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 pi -1 ps 1

plot FILE u ($0==0?(x0=$1,y0=$2):0,x1=$1):(y1=$2) w lp ls 1, \
      '+' u (x0):(y0):(x1-x0):(y1-y0) every ::::0 w vec nohead ls 1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]