# Sorting data by angle and radial distance from origin in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

For context: I am plotting the k_x,k_y coordinates for the intersection of some energy bands in a brillouin zone with a certain energy value.

However, the problem can be heavily simplified.

- My data is in the form of two rings
- I need to connect all the points in gnuplot in the outer ring and all the points in the inner ring WHILST ensuring that the rings are not connected to eachother

Image shows the current state of my band plot (PS. pls ignore the anomalous point towards the bottom right I am ignoring this until the bandplot is better):

[image]

- So far I have achieved the angular sorting but I cannot work out how to separate the two rings. I assume it will likely be done easiest using some kind of pythagoras radial-distance sorting but I am struggling to implement this.

Achieved with following gnuplot file, 'kmesh.plt':

```
set xrange [-0.1 : 0.1]
set title "2D k-mesh plot at 20meV above CBM"
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced font "DejaVu" transparent 
fontscale 1 size 5.00in, 5.00in
set output "kmesh.pdf"
set encoding iso_8859_1
set size ratio 0 1.0,1.0
set ylabel "k_y coordinate"
set xlabel "k_x coordinate"
set yrange [ -0.1 : 0.1 ]
unset key
set ytics 0.05 scale 1 nomirror out
set mytics 2
set parametric
set trange [-10:10]
set multiplot
set style data linespoints
plot "kmesh.dat" using 1:2:(atan2($2,$1)):(atan2($2,$1)) smooth         
zsort
unset multiplot
```

Comment: The graph looks like the points are strictly alternating (inner ring, outer ring), correct? Is the graph already the sorted data? Please provide your original k_x, k_y input data.

Comment: Yeah it does look like that, I am only sorting by angle though not radial distance at this point so It could be said that within the angle between two outer points, there is generally an inner point. Here is the input data:   https://pastebin.com/J753SE2B

Comment: Thank you for posting the data! This helps a lot. Well, the data points are not strictly alternating between inside and outside ring. Anyway, it doesn't matter, see my answer attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a request for clarification rather than a proper answer (there wasn't enough room in a comment).

Could you please clarify what exactly is in columns 1 and 2 of your data file?
[x,y] cartesian coordinates?
[θ,r] polar coordinates?

Your script is a bit of a mess. It says `set parametric`, but parametric form is for functions, not data files. Did you mean `set polar` instead? Then it says `set multiplot` but that is followed by only a single plot.

I take it that the 3rd `using` field in the plot command is to be interpreted as z for the sort operation but is really θ (assuming columns 1 and 2 are x and y); that is clever.  But what is the 4th field intended to do?

It is possible that the commands below will do what you want, but without a sample of your data I cannot be sure.

```
# generate some artificial data
set table $DATA
plot '+' using ((rand(0)-0.5)/5) : ((rand(0)-0.5)/5)
unset table

 
# plot it
set xrange [-0.1 : 0.1]; set yrange [-0.1 : 0.1]
set size square
R(x,y) = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
theta(x,y) = atan2(y,x)
gap = 0.05
set style data linespoints
set datafile missing NaN
plot $DATA using (R($1,$2) < gap ? $1 : NaN) : ($2) : (theta($1,$2)) smooth zsort, \
     $DATA using (R($1,$2) > gap ? $1 : NaN) : ($2) : (theta($1,$2)) smooth zsort
```

**Notes:**

- There is no need to use parametric mode or multiplot.  Using polar mode would be an option, but if the data is in Cartesian coordinates I don't think that will be any easier.
- I am not certain of the order in which the program will sort on theta and filter against R.  If gaps are introduced, the points you want to connect may not be adjacent and the line would be interrupted. `set datafile missing NaN` may mitigate this.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I have tried implementing your functions and they are doing exactly what I wanted. Just to clear it up:
- My data is in a cartesian coordinate basis
- I am using multiplot to superpose a vector plot on top of these points which I omitted for the sake of clarity (but i dont need parametric). The only thing is, as you mentioned, there may be an issue with line discontinuity. The plot is continuous everywhere (despite data discontinuities) EXCEPT for one range of discontinuity along the - y axis (180 degrees).  Could this be to do with the atan2 calculation?

Comment: Images for clarity: one shows the points and one shows the linespoints plot that connects them. https://imgur.com/a/RtAwKcg

Comment: I think that is just the gap between the last point and the first point.  I.e.  points gets sorted 1...N  and line segments connect 1-2 2-3 ... (N-1)-N  but nothing connects N back to 1.  Usually one doesn't want the end points of a line to be connected.  Your case is unusual in that regard.  At the moment I can't think of a solution other than drawing each curve twice, the second time using e.g. theta = atan2 + π.   The two curves would superimpose everywhere except that one would have a gap at π and one at -π

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. More or less the only way to sort within gnuplot is `smooth zsort`, available since gnuplot 5.4.0. (Just as a side note: be aware if you want to sort by two columns the Windows version of `zsort` for some reason does not preserve the order. See: [How to sort a datablock in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67801386/7295599)).

The following script is similar to Ethan's script with the addition of closing the rings by "simply" remembering the first and the last coordinates of the respective rings and [closing it with a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76075844/7295599).

Some comments:

- sort the data by angle and split it by inner and outer ring
- the function `RingX(colX,colY,b)` has the input parameters: x- and y-column of your data and `b=0` for inner and `b=1` for outer ring, where the separation is at a radius of `0.04`. The function returns the x-value if it's on the selected ring and `NaN` otherwise. `^` is exclusive OR (XOR).
- furthermore, during plotting of the (open) ring the first and last coordinates will be remembered in `x0,y0` and `x2,y2` by using a flag `f`.
- the closing of the rings will be done by plotting style `with vectors`

Maybe the script can be further simplified.

*Edit:*
The original lines  `'' u (x0):(y0):(x2-x0):(y2-y0) w vec` would plot the closing vector as many times on top of each other as `$Sorted` has data lines. This can be avoided by using `'+' u (x0):(y0):(x2-x0):(y2-y0) every ::::0 w vec`. This is one way to add a single data point (or line/segment) to a graph.

**Data:** `SO77526588.dat`

```
   -0.051059    0.021747
   -0.050222    0.023197
   -0.045200    0.031895
   -0.044363    0.033345
   -0.051896    0.017397
   -0.041015    0.036245
   -0.052733    0.013048
   -0.037667    0.039144
   -0.052733    0.010148
   -0.035155    0.040594
   -0.052733   -0.010148
   -0.017578    0.050742
   -0.052733   -0.013048
   -0.015067    0.052192
   -0.051896   -0.017397
   -0.010881    0.053642
   -0.051059   -0.021747
   -0.033481    0.008699
   -0.032644    0.010148
   -0.025111    0.023197
   -0.024274    0.024646
   -0.006696    0.055092
   -0.050222   -0.023197
   -0.034318    0.004349
   -0.020926    0.027546
   -0.005022    0.055092
   -0.034318    0.001450
   -0.018415    0.028996
   -0.034318   -0.001450
   -0.015904    0.030445
   -0.034318   -0.004349
   -0.013393    0.031895
   -0.033481   -0.008699
   -0.009207    0.033345
   -0.045200   -0.031895
   -0.032644   -0.010148
   -0.007533    0.033345
    0.005022    0.055092
   -0.044363   -0.033345
    0.006696    0.055092
   -0.041015   -0.036245
    0.010881    0.053642
   -0.037667   -0.039144
    0.015067    0.052192
   -0.035155   -0.040594
   -0.025111   -0.023197
    0.007533    0.033345
    0.017578    0.050742
   -0.024274   -0.024646
    0.009207    0.033345
   -0.020926   -0.027546
    0.013393    0.031895
   -0.018415   -0.028996
    0.015904    0.030445
   -0.015904   -0.030445
    0.018415    0.028996
   -0.013393   -0.031895
    0.020926    0.027546
   -0.009207   -0.033345
    0.024274    0.024646
   -0.017578   -0.050742
   -0.007533   -0.033345
    0.025111    0.023197
    0.035155    0.040594
   -0.015067   -0.052192
    0.037667    0.039144
   -0.010881   -0.053642
    0.041015    0.036245
   -0.006696   -0.055092
    0.044363    0.033345
   -0.005022   -0.055092
    0.007533   -0.033345
    0.032644    0.010148
    0.045200    0.031895
    0.009207   -0.033345
    0.033481    0.008699
    0.013393   -0.031895
    0.034318    0.004349
    0.015904   -0.030445
    0.034318    0.001450
    0.018415   -0.028996
    0.034318   -0.001450
    0.005022   -0.055092
    0.020926   -0.027546
    0.034318   -0.004349
    0.050222    0.023197
    0.006696   -0.055092
    0.024274   -0.024646
    0.025111   -0.023197
    0.032644   -0.010148
    0.033481   -0.008699
    0.051059    0.021747
    0.010881   -0.053642
    0.051896    0.017397
    0.015067   -0.052192
    0.052733    0.013048
    0.017578   -0.050742
    0.052733    0.010148
    0.035155   -0.040594
    0.052733   -0.010148
    0.037667   -0.039144
    0.052733   -0.013048
    0.041015   -0.036245
    0.051896   -0.017397
    0.044363   -0.033345
    0.045200   -0.031895
    0.050222   -0.023197
    0.051059   -0.021747
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### sort data by angle and split by radius and close curve
reset session

FILE = "SO77526588.dat"

set table $Sorted
    plot FILE u 1:2:(atan2($2,$1))  smooth zsort
unset table

set size ratio -1
set datafile missing NaN
set key noautotitle
set xlabel "k_x coordinate" font ",12"
set ylabel "k_y coordinate" font ",12"
set style line 1 lw 7 lc rgb 0xaaaaff
set style line 2 lw 7 lc rgb 0xffaaaa

RingX(colX,colY,b) = (x1=column(colX), y1=column(colY), sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2) < 0.04)^b ? \
                     (f ? (y2=y1,x2=x1):(f=1,y0=y1,x0=x1)) : NaN
angle(colX,colY)   = atan2(column(colY),column(colX))

plot f=0 $Sorted u (RingX(1,2,0)):2:(angle(1,2))         w l   ls 1, \
             '+' u (x0):(y0):(x2-x0):(y2-y0) every ::::0 w vec ls 1 nohead, \
     f=0 $Sorted u (RingX(1,2,1)):2:(angle(1,2))         w l   ls 2, \
             '+' u (x0):(y0):(x2-x0):(y2-y0) every ::::0 w vec ls 2 nohead, \
            FILE u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc "black"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]